# Algorithm for finding ranges which include a number

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting, range

Say you have a "Range" type like this (pseudocode):

```
Range {
    int lowerBound
    int upperBound
}
```

And you have a collection of ranges, where ranges may overlap:

```
var ranges = [Range{2, 5}, Range{8, 12}, Range{1, 3}, ...]
```

Given an integer *i*, what is an efficient way of retrieving every range which contains *i* (i.e. lowerBound < *i* < upperBound)?

#### Possible solutions I've come up with:

A naive O(n) way to do this would of course be to iterate over the ranges and return each range where lowerBound < *i* < upperBound. But I need to run the algorithm many times for different *i* values and there are millions of ranges, so this naive solution is unacceptable.

A more efficient solution would be to sort the ranges in ascending order by the value of lowerBound. This way, the algorithm only needs to iterate through the ranges until it reaches the first range where lowerBound > *i* (because it is impossible for a range to include *i* if lowerBound > *i*).

This could be further improved if we sort all the *i* values before feeding them into the algorithm (actually, in my implementation the *i* values are already given in ascending order, so we don't lose any performance by having to "sort" them). By doing this, we would be able to delete ranges from the collection if their upperBound is less than a given *i* value, resulting in fewer comparisons for future *i* values. This method is the most efficient solution I've come up with so far, but I'm struggling to implement it due to the fact that ranges are allowed to overlap. Because ranges can overlap and given the fact that we sorted the ranges by lowerBound, the only way to find ranges where upperBound < *i* would be to iterate through them in O(n). How can I finish implementing this solution efficiently? (Or is there a totally different solution that is more efficient?)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree#Query, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Intersecting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree). Its leaves correspond to the distinct boundary values that you have in your ranges, and they represent the interval up to the next boundary. So these intervals do not overlap. Its nodes hold information about which (larger) interval they represent -- the union of the leaf intervals below it. For each leaf you also determine (once) which ranges are "open" in that interval.

Using binary search you can find the leaf that represents the interval that has your search value, and so you also get from that leaf which ranges apply.

It works best if you define your ranges in such a way that the ending index is *beyond* the range (not included).

For your example `[Range{2, 5}, Range{8, 12}, Range{1, 3}]`, the leaves would be:

```
[1, 2): [Range{1, 3}]
[2, 3): [Range{1, 3}, Range{2, 5}]
[3, 5): [Range{2, 5}]
[5, 8): []
[8, 12): [Range{8, 12}]
```